# Не работает расширение Code Run для VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

В консоле отображается такие символы. В чем может быть дело?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего выводит что-то типа "node не является внутренней или внешней командой". Значит надо в переменной окружения path добавить папку, в которой лежит node. Или в настройках расширения (code runner: executor map) для javascript прописать полный путь до node.exe (или чем у вас должен ваш файл запускаться).

Comment: как точно называется расширение? (лучше ссылку), возможно проблема со шрифтами а не самим расширением

Answer (score 0):

Возможно проблема со шрифтами а не самим расширением, если нужен просто запуск можно просто в терминале писать `node ./script.js`  или настроить `npm init`  (с прописыванием скрипта: "start", пример на скрине )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Даная проблема возникает если в системе не установлена программа Node.js. Плагин CodeRunner работает не сам по себе, а на основе Node.js Установите данную программу и получите корректное отображение информации.

Comment: Естественно, это только для JS. Для каждого языка ставить свои компиляторы/интерпретаторы/...

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю прочтёшь или нет)) Просто надо поставить галочку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Будут нормальные буквы. (в т. ч. русские) А также будет работать ввод.